# Homotopy extension property with maps at both ends fixed.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider the following property of a map $\iota : A \to X$. Given any pair of maps $f, g : X \to Z$ and a homotopy $H : A \times I \to Z$ between $f \circ \iota$ and $g \circ \iota$ it can be extended to a homotopy $H' : X \times I \to Z$ between $f$ and $g$.

If any map $g : A \to Z$ can be extended to a map $g' : X \to Z$ then the above property implies the homotopy extension property (HEP).

In general, does this property imply HEP, does HEP imply this property, is it equivalent to HEP?

Comment: Consider for example the case $A = *$, $X$ well-pointed, $Z$ path-connected, but $f$ and $g$ are not homotopy equivalent.  In terms of lifting properties, if $A \to X$ is a cofibration, then $(X \times \{0\}) \cup_{A \times \{0\}} (A \times I) \hookrightarrow X \times I$ is an acyclic cofibration and has the left lifting property against $Z \to *$.  However, $(X \times \{0,1\}) \cup_{A \times \{0,1\}} (A \times I) \hookrightarrow X \times I$ is not usually acyclic.

Comment: It's worth noting that a subspace inclusion $i:A\subseteq X$ is a deformation retract ($=$ $i$ is a homotopy equivalence with inverse $r:X\rightarrow A$ satisfying $r\circ i=id_A$ strictly) iff $i)$ any map $A\rightarrow Z$ extends over $X$, and $ii)$ if $f,g:X\rightarrow Z$ are maps such that $f|_A\simeq g|_A$, then $f\simeq g$. This doesn't satisfy the stronger property about extending homotopies strictly, however. If $i$ is a strong deformation retract (so that $i\circ r\simeq id_X$ rel $A$), then the homotopy that gets extended is $f|_A+H+g|_A$.

Comment: Please clarify if you consider a *single space* $Z$ or if you want that *all* $Z$ have this property.

Comment: @PaulFrost I want $A \to X$ to have this property with respect to pairs of maps $f, g : X \to Z$ to *any* $Z$.